# What is the integral under the Gaussian distribution in the context of a-posteriori estimation?

Tags: normal-distribution

According to my text book about Pattern Recognition **(Bishop)**, the predictive distribution is defined as the following
$$p(t_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \vec{x}, \vec{t})
= \int p(t_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \vec{w})\cdot p(\vec{w}| \vec{x}, \vec{t})\:\mathrm{d}\vec{w}$$
with $dim(x)=dim(t)=n$ so that $n+1$ denotes a newly received value while
$\vec{x}$ is the vector of all former inputs and $\vec{t}$ is the vector of all former target outputs. The probability of $t_{n+1}$ is here expressed as relying on all known input-output/target combinations and the corresponding new input. $\vec{w}$ is the vector of all previously defined paramters describing the function that is the best known regression for all known input-output combinations (e. g. found through least squares method or similar).

Both functions under the integral are modelled as Gaussian distributions.

But the solutions of the equation above states
$$p(t_{n+1}|x_{n+1}, \vec{x}, \vec{t})=\mathcal{N}(t_{n+1}|m(x_{n+1}), s^2(x_{n+1}))$$
with parameters $m,s$ that are constant for one choice of all parameters above
and are not varying over time or similar. Thus, the latter equation says that the result is a Gaussian again. But since the integral under a Gaussian is
an S-shaped curve, that does not make sense to me. Has it something to do with
the multi-dimensionality?

Comment: This is eq. 3.57 of Bishop PRML. He says it’s the convolution of two Gaussians so eq 2.115 applies and the result follows. Eq. 2.115 is derived in section 2.3.3.

Comment: He isn't integrating out $t_{n+1}$, which would lead to the cumulative density function (or "S-shaped curve") if there were a finite upper limit on the integral, but one of the parameters, in this case, the mean (which can itself be a function of several parameters.)